# Sketch complex curve $z(t) = e^{-1t+it}$, $0 \le t \le b$ for some $b>0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Sketch complex curve $z(t) = e^{-1t+it}$, $0 \le t \le b$ for some $b>0$

I tried plotting this using mathematica, but I get two curves.
Also, how do I find its length, is it just the integral?

This equation doesn't converge right?

Edit: I forgot the $t$ in front of the $1$ so it's not a circle of radius $e$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You have received answers for the rest, so let me focus on the length.)

The length of the curve is given by
$$\int_0^b |z'(t)|\,dt = \int_0^b |(-1+i)e^{(-1+i)t}|\,dt = \int_0^b \sqrt 2 e^{-t}\,dt.$$
I think you can work out what happens when $b\to\infty$ now.

Comment: Ah thanks! Pretty much had this question wrong, thanks for saving me.

Answer (score 1):

This curve clearly lies on a circle of radius $e$ (since $\|z(t) \| \equiv e$).

If $b>2 \pi$ then the curve will repeat itself.

The curve has finite length (unless $b=\infty$ of course).

Comment: I had the equation wrong its exp(-t + it)

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
e^{-t+it}=e^{t(-1+i)}=e^{-t}(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))
$$
the image you're trying to find is an arc of a spiral with center on the origin, where the angular range is $[0,b]$.

Comment: sorry, the actual equation is exp(-t + it)

Comment: I have corrected my answer. Take a look.

Comment: what do you mean by angular range?

Comment: It means that the angle goes from $0$ to $b$.

Comment: Also, the length of this curve does not converge correct? as b goes to infinity that is

Comment: I believe that it does. Not sure though.